# Load different components on tab change

Tags: polymer

In the context of an SPA I want to have 3 different 'views' (for want of a better word). The first one is a set of filters that can be applied to large list of restaurants, the second one is a listing of filtered restaurants, and the third one plots locations on a map.

All the demos I can find so far basically just show different content in the same template when you switch tabs, whereas I want to use very different template and content on each one (https://github.com/Polymer/docs/blob/master/0.5/elements/demo-tabs.html is the closest I've found so far).

Based on the input in the comments, I now have

```
<body unresolved>
    <core-scaffold>
        <core-header-panel>
            <core-toolbar>
                <text-span>
                    AF Mobile
                </text-span>
                <paper-input></paper-input>
            </core-toolbar>
            <core-toolbar>
                <paper-tabs id="tabs" selected="list" self-end>
                    <paper-tab name="criteria">Criteria</paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab name="list">List</paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab name="map">Map</paper-tab>
                </paper-tabs>
            </core-toolbar>
            <core-pages selected="list" valueattr="hash">
                <div hash="list" class="container" layout vertical center>
                    <resto-list show="all"></resto-list> 
                </div>
                <div id="mapHolder" hash="map">
                    <google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942"></google-map>
                </div>
            </core-pages>
        </core-header-panel>

    </core-scaffold>

<script>
    var tabs = document.querySelector('paper-tabs');
    var pages = document.querySelector('core-pages');

    tabs.addEventListener('core-select', function() {
        console.log("Selected: " + tabs.selected);
        pages.selected = tabs.selected;
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867304/single-page-app-architecture-with-polymer.

The demo on that page shows how to use `core-pages` to achieve what you want. Each child element of core-pages is your different content. You can then data bind the `selected` attribute of paper-tabs to core-pages's `selected` attribute.

Comment: @Simon H Could you please post your solution to your question. I have the same question. Thanks